# Pass a user defined table to a SqlCommand (which doesn't execute a stored procedure)

Tags: sql-server, parameters, ado.net

I'm trying to use a user-defined table with a simple `SqlCommand` (which doesn't execute a stored procedure).
I get the message `Must declare the scalar variable`, although the parameter is already defined.

Code (assume `accountIds` is defined elsewhere, so that `dtAccountIds` has some values):

```
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(); 
sqlCommand.CommandText =
@"SELECT * INTO #RecordsToLog
    FROM Accounts
    WHERE [AccountId] IN (@AccountIds)";

var dtAccountIds = new DataTable();
dtAccountIds.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
accountIds.ToList().ForEach(id => dtAccountIds.Rows.Add(id));
sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountIds", dtAccountIds).TypeName = "dbo.IdsTable";

sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The user-defined table was created with:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IdsTable] AS TABLE([id] [int] NULL)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly, your SQL code is wrong.** The table parameter is a table variable, so you need a full subquery `IN (SELECT id FROM @AccountIds)`.

Quite why you are inserting into a temp table, I don't know, you haven't given us any context.

**Next, [you shouldn't use `AddWithValue`](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/),** instead declare the exact type `SqlDbType.Structured`, along with `Direction` and `TypeName`

Also, I hope you are not caching the connection object. **You must dispose the connection and command object.**

```cs
const string query = @"
SELECT *
INTO #RecordsToLog
    FROM Accounts
    WHERE [AccountId] IN
      (SELECT id FROM @AccountIds)
";

using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
{
    var dtAccountIds = new DataTable { Columns = { { "id", typeof(int) } } };
    foreach (var id in accountIds)
        dtAccountIds.Rows.Add(id);
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AccountIds", SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            Value = dtAccountIds,
            TypeName = "dbo.IdsTable",
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
        });

    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, especially for the link explaining why it's bad. Just to clarify for future readers: The obvious problem was the wrong script (`IN (@AccountIds)`), while `AddWithValue` is bad for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You must configure the parameter as `SqlDbType.Structured`. Avoid using `AddWithValue`, let me suggest this notation:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@AccountIds", SqlDbType.Structured, 0)
{
    Value = dtAccountIds
}
```

According to MS-DOCS about [SqlDbType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype?view=net-5.0):

> **Structured** = A special data type for specifying structured data contained in table-valued parameters.